# Access service recovery count

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-service

I am looking for a way to access a services' recovery count in Windows 2008 and 2003.  From services.msc on the recovery tab you can set actions on first, second and subsequent failures.   I would like to get a count of these failures by service.   Is there a WMI point which can give me this information or someway else?

I know I can script something as well, though I would to see if there is anything available in the OS first.